# Restore Xfce menu after installing program from flatpak

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, configuration, menu

I'm running Xubuntu (Ubuntu Studio which is based on Xubuntu), and I somehow messed up my applications menu. I had the original menu, with the favorites on the left side and the applications grouped by theme (accessories, education, games, internet, etc) on the right hand side.

I installed PiTiVi from flatpak (I know, I should have installed it using the synaptic package manager). Now, I still have my favorites on the left side, but the right side shows only "All".

How can I restore the default Xfce menu?

(Before and after attached. Before is from a virtual machine, with no personal favorites added.)

[image]

Comment: DK Bose - thanks for the suggestion. I thought that I was clarifying my request. Based on your comment, I actually made my question less clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received an answer here. Though the whiskermenu-1.rc was part of the issue, it was a little more complicated than that. Here is the solution:

> **ToZ (moderator)** #10 2019-01-20 15:00:53
>
> Looks like you ran flatpak with root privileges and it somehow messed up your menu generation (the menu creation routines cannot access a directory in your $XDG_DATA_DIRS path).
>
> To fix it, run the following:
>
> ```
> sudo chown $USER:$USER $HOME/.local/share/flatpak
> ```
>
> ...and restart the panel:
>
> ```
> xfce4-panel -r
> ```

Original thread: [XFCE Forum - Restore XFCE menu](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=12752)